# How can I generate MarkLogic database reports?

Tags: marklogic, database-administration

How can we generate database reports in MarkLogic without having putty access to the server?

Let's say I want to generate a report which lists out the backup information of my MarkLogic Server. What tools and scripting do I need to use to get such type of report or if any alert mail I want to configure if anything fails at the server level.

Comment: There are a number of options. APIs are available to obtain any of the information that you would want to report on by executing JavaScript or XQuery modules, but you would need to decide how to orchestrate or schedule(MarkLogic scheduled task, external service invoking a MarkLogic endpoint, etc). Have you considered using Ops Director and configuring email alerts? https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/opsdir/ConsoleSettings#id_98801

Comment: There are also REST endpoints that can provide much of the information an administrator would want to see, but Ops Director is likely the easiest option if you want it to include alerting.